# changing image's bounds depends on image's size

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, size, bounds

I am trying to make the UIImage object's bounds to be changed depends on the image size. I do not know why the image bounds would not update

```
@interface AsunaEventViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *AsunaImageView;
@end

@implementation AsunaEventViewController
CGFloat x = self.AsunaImageView.bounds.center.x; 
CGFloat y = self.AsunaImageView.bounds.center.y;
if (self.answer == 0){ 
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"qwr.png"] size]; 
    CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(x - imageSize.width/2, y - imageSize.height/2, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    self.AsunaImageView.frame = imageBounds; 
    self.AsunaImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rts.png"]
```

Comment: Where are you updating the frame of image view? Make sure the view is not `nil` or loaded before you update its properties. Or may be that your self.answer is 0.

Comment: you are getting the size of image `qwr.png` and loading the imageview with `rts.png`, is it correct?

Comment: can i delete my qus now @ nazik

Comment: Pls accept the answer, if it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Change the image name of the UIImageview

```
if (self.answer == 0){ 
   CGSize imageSize = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"qwr.png"] size]; 
   CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(x - imageSize.width/2, y - imageSize.height/2, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
   self.AsunaImageView.frame = imageBounds; 
   self.AsunaImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"qwr.png"];
}
```